# Warning: mysqli_connect(): Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some trouble connecting to a mysql server. I can connect using the linux terminal, so I know that my host, port, user, and password works. I cannot, however, connect using PHP.

**PHP Version:** 5.2.17

**Server version:** 5.5.27-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Here is a test code example:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('host.com:5306', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

/* check connection */

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);    

?>
```

Gives the following warning:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'host.com:5306' (1) in /.../test.php on line 3
>
> Connect failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'host.com:5306' (1)

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: have you tried using localhost instead of host:5306?

Comment: if MYsql server is on local machine where you are running PHP use localhost or 127.0.0.1 ip address, it gives faster access as well and will connect.

Comment: Instead of "host" do you mean "localhost" ?

Comment: It is not on a local machine!

Comment: I also had problems under linux using the host:port notation. separating the host and port into their specific parameter positions fixed it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The port number must be a separate argument:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', 5306);
```

Answer (score 5):

> Any ideas on what to do?

Sure. A simple three-step solution for any php function's problem:

1. Open your favorite browser
2. type `php.net/` in the address bar followed by a problem function's name:
   `php.net/mysqli_connect` in your case
3. Hit Enter

Now you have the function's description and can check the proper parameters list.

Answer (score 0):

The host parameter in the mysql function need to be "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"

You set the parameter as "host:port" and that is your mistake. It's need to be the full alias of the network in the server or the remote server with the full IP address. You can found more information about this error here: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/127_0_0_1_def.htm

The mysql book in php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

host is the IP of your mysql server, or maybe "localhost"